# Basic R: Summing the product of two variables?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and don't really know how to do this basic technique. I have a dataset and I am looking to sum the product of the two vectors, `X` and `Y`, of length n, i.e:

sum from 0 to n of X_i * Y_i

Can anyone help me out in executing this basic line of code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- (1:10)
b <- (2:11)

sum(a*b)
```

On a dataframe the answer is the same:

```
df <- data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11))
sum(df$a*df$b)
```

Mathjax is not supported in stackoverflow :(